# python left excluding join between 2 dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, merge

I have two dataframes A and B that have the same structure and a key_id column that I can use to join them.

Basically, I only want to retain rows from dataframe A that do NOT appear in dataframe B.

This is a left excluding join but I can't really find my way to implement it.

[image: Left Excluding Join]

Comment: See the "Other JOINs - LEFT-Excluding, RIGHT-Excluding, and FULL-Excluding/ANTI JOINs" section

Comment: Thanks Henry. It does!